# Difference between flashable firmware files of 2 same model phone with different internal SD size?

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, device-firmware, stock-rom

I have a Gionee m2 8gb which is in a bootloop, so I downloaded flashable firmware files for it, but mistakenly I downloaded gionee m2 4gb flashable firmware files. Is it possible to use this files for my phone with some minor changes?

Comment: Its a difference in the files (partition images) responsible for determining the partition table and size. You can use it, but you would end up getting your 8GB device a partition layout for a 4GB device. This would cause half the available app storage (i.e., the data partition's size would be approximately halved). I suggest you redownload the correct firmware, as otherwise you will have to repartition your device which is a very (hard-brick) risky proposition.